# SSL certificates on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

I am currently using GCP for hosting my website. I do have a custom domain and the SSL security is Google-managed. However, when I go to my website. I still get this

[image]

Comment: What GCP product are you using? Also what are the domain (including subdomain) name(s) for your project?

Comment: I am currently using Google App Engine at the moment.

Comment: This warning message means that some of your website is being delivered over HTTPS and some over HTTP. Use your browsers' debugger network tab, refresh the page and look at the images, css, js, etc. urls being downloaded. Make sure everything is using https in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixed content. Your page is trying to retrieve/load images/icons from non-SSL (HTTP) sources. Look for scripts/html code with image src pointing to HTTP rather than HTTPS URLs and replace them with HTTPS URLs.